# Problems with the foreach-Loop, to get proper Output as an XML-File

Tags: c#, xml, linq, enterprise-architect

i am currently working with Enterprise Architect(EA) and I am writing a little AddIn to extract the Attributes and the Attributevalues from the Model-Diagram and extract it to an XML-File. How to use the EA-API is no Problem, but because I am pretty new to C#, I have problems with the C#-Implementation:

First I post the Code, then a piece of the Output file and then an example what kind of output I want. So at least the Question will have a structure, better than my code ;)

```
String writerString3;
String tagString3;
tagString3 = "";
writerString3 = "";


foreach (EA.Element thePackages in myPackage.Packages)
   { // myPackage = the package I select by MenuClick

    foreach (EA.Element theElements in myPackage.Elements)
     {

      foreach (EA.Attribute theAttribute in theElements.Attributes)
      {

        XElement toXML = new XElement(myPackage.Name.ToString(),
        (new XElement(theElements.Name.ToString(),
        (new XAttribute(theAttribute.Name.ToString(), theAttribute.Default.ToString())))));
        tagString3 = tagString3 + toXML;

       }
      writerString3 = writerString3 + tagString3;
      tagString3 = "";
      }
  }

  foreach (EA.Element theElements in myPackage.Elements)
  {

   foreach (EA.Attribute theAttribute in theElements.Attributes)
   {
    XElement toXML = new XElement(myPackage.Name.ToString(),
    (new XElement(theElements.Name.ToString(),
    (new XAttribute(theAttribute.Name.ToString(), theAttribute.Default.ToString())))));
    tagString3 = tagString3 + toXML;

    }
    writerString3 = writerString3 + tagString3;
    tagString3 = "";
      }

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(myPackage.Name.ToString() + ".xml");
    tw.WriteLine(writerString3);
    tw.Close(); }
```

The Output looks like this: //shortened version

```
<Application01>
  <App01 Name="App01" />
</Application01><Application01>
  <App01 ApplicationDomain="xyz" />
</Application01><Application01>
  <App01 AbstractionLevel="" />
</Application01><Application01>
  <App01_Communication Type="CAN" />
</Application01><Application01>
```

It goes on like this, with all the Elements and Attributes listet in each line. I know the code is wrong, but I cannot fix it in a proper way. First I pick a package, iterate through the Elements and for each Element I want to output the related Atrributes plus values. 
E.g:
Element1
Attrbute11, Attribute12, Attribute13
Element2
Attrbute21, Attribute22, Attribute23

And so on...My prefered XML-File should look like this:

```
<packageName>
  <Element1>
    <Attribute11>value11</Attribute11>
    <Attribute22>value22</Attribute22>
    <Attribute33>value33</Attribute33>
  </Element1>
  <Element2>
    <Attribute21>value21</Attribute21>
    <Attribute22>value22</Attribute22>
    <Attribute23>value23</Attribute23>
  </Element2>
</packageName>
```

I hope i could make my problem clear. I wouldn't ask if I couldn't do it on my own. Of course if somebody know how to get the Attributes and Elements out of the Diagrams with a different way, I would be happy to hear that(besides the tools given by EA).
Thanks for reading and many thanks fpr helping ;)

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which describes the problem you're facing.

Comment: you've been right, the title was not optimal, I hope this is better.

Comment: You have elements called AttributeNN but you should not be using XAttribute.

Comment: Please check: is it `foreach (EA.Element theElements in myPackage.Elements)` or the more logical `foreach (EA.Element theElements in thePackages.Elements)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two separate loops at the outermost level, first off. This doesn't seem useful.

Secondly, you are looping over the `myPackage.Packages` collection, then each time through that loop you do nothing with the loop variable `myPackages` but simply launch into the inner loop which does the work. So you end up with one copy of each element for each subpackage in myPackage (and none if there are no subpackages). So clearly that has to go.

Finally, setting up an XElement as a formatter and then successively copying the XML data into your own string is probably not the best solution. It's better to use XElement to construct the XML tree first and then dump the contents.

So it should look something like this (not tested, not compiled):

```
XElement xPkg = new XElement(myPackage.Name.ToString());

foreach (EA.Element theElement in myPackage.Elements)
{
    XElement xElem = new XElement(theElement.Name.ToString());
    xPkg.Add(xElem);
    foreach (EA.Attribute theAttribute in theElement.Attributes)
    {
        XAttribute xAttr = new XAttribute(theAttribute.Name.ToString(),
                                          theAttribute.Default.ToString()));
        xElem.Add(xAttr);
    }
}

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(myPackage.Name.ToString() + ".xml");
tw.WriteLine(xPkg.ToString());
tw.Close();
```

Comment: thank you very much uffe, works perfectly :) Little correction to your Code, it should be XAttribute xAttr = new XAttribute...

Comment: Thanks! :) And I edited the post to incorporate your correction.